# On my webpage, using "window.location.href" returns "about:srcdoc" instead of the URL name

Tags: javascript, html, url

To see the problem, enter this URL "https://gainesrad.com/readqrcodefromkiosk/"

It should display the URL of the webpage but instead I get "about:srcdoc".

Here is the HTML code on gainesrad.com/readqrcodefromkiosk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<b>This should tell me the URL of the page but instead is says "about:srcdoc"</b>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The full URL is:  " + window.location.href;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `top.location.href` when in the same domain

Answer (score 1):

The `srcdoc`attribute is used in Iframe context to indicate the content of an iframe.
While inspecting the full source code of your page, I noticed you are using an iframe, and that's why you are getting `about:srcdoc` with `window.location.href`

To get the URL move the inline `<script>` to the document context outside the Iframe.

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc

Since your iframe is contained within the Document context, you can do this to retrieve the base URI of the containing document:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument

```
   let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
   console.log('The baseURI is: ' + iframe.contentDocument.baseURI)
```

Comment: Thank you Micah for responding.  It sounds like you have the answer but I having trouble because I do not understand how to move the inline <script> outside the Iframe (I didn't even know I was using an Iframe).  I checked out your recommended link but I still am not sure how to write the code.  I tried moving the <script> below the <html> but it didn't work (e.g. I did this):

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<b>This should tell me the URL of the page but instead is says "about:srcdoc"</b>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The full URL is:  " + window.location.href;
</script>

Comment: Can you help me move  the inline <script> outside the Iframe?

Comment: @BobGaines, on checking out the head section of the generated HTML page, you are using a site generator that is injecting your content into the iframe so that's why you didn't know you were using an iframe. I have updated my answer to include a workaround solution. See if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You all were right.  I called godaddy and since I am using Website Builder I am in an iFrame.
To do what I need on godaddy, I had to purchase web hosting and stop using Website Builder.
Thanks to everyone for the help.