# javascript bookmarklet - window.location.href passes about:srcdoc instead of url - how to move inline <script> outside the Iframe

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I having issue with the code below. What I try to achieve is a javascript bookmarklet (I use the code below in https://katanya.co.uk/labs/bookmarklet-generator), which opens a popup, asked the user for some input (Where is the problem, what is the problem) and passes the input into a URL, together with some static values - which looks like this:

https://internal_ticketsystem.com/create/options?title=Colour+Change%2CTR%2815%29%2Ccompany+A%28123%29&description=Hello%2C%0AI+have+the+following+issue%3A%0Atest%0A%0A***CHOOSE+THE+DEFECT%3A***%0AImage+is+red+but+shouldnt%0A%0Aon+following+URL+%0Aabout%3Asrcdoc&ticket_type=Regular%2BTicket&severity=TWENTY&cat=Catalogue&subcat=Support&topic=Changes

The problem that I currently have is, getting the current user location (I use window.location.href) into the result. I only get 'about:srcdoc' instead of the URL.

```
javascript:(function(){

   (function( window, document, req_version, callback, $, script, done, readystate ){
      
      if ( !($ = window.jQuery) || req_version > $.fn.jquery || callback( $ ) ) {
        
        script = document.createElement( 'script' );
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        
        script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' + req_version + '/jquery.min.js';
        
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if ( !done && ( !( readystate = this.readyState )
            || readystate == 'loaded' || readystate == 'complete' ) ) {
            
            callback( ($ = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), done = 1 );
            
            $( script ).remove();
          }
        };
        
        document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild( script );
      }
      
    })( window, document, '1.3.2',
     
      function( $, L ) {
        '$:nomunge, L:nomunge';
            $('#papercutModal').remove();
            $(`
                <div id="papercutModal" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; display: block; overflow: auto; background-color: #000000; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); z-index: 9999;">
                    <div id="papercutCard" style="position: relative; background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 10% auto; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
                        <iframe id="papercutFrame" style='border:none;' width='100%' height='100%' srcdoc='
                            <html>
                            <head>
                            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <style type="text/css">     
                            
                                body {
                                  font-family: Amazon Ember,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                                }               
                                
                                .btn {
                                    border-radius: 2px;
                                    font-weight: 700;
                                    padding: 4px 20px;
                                    border: 1px solid #545b64;
                                    /* margin-top: 5px;
                                    margin-bottom: 5px; */
                                    margin-right: 5px;
                                    text-align: center;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    color: #545b64;
                                    background: #FFFFFF;
                                }
                                
                                .btn:hover {
                                    color: #16191f;
                                    background: #fafafa;
                                }
                                
                                .btn:active {
                                    background: #eaeded;
                                }
                                
                                .btn-primary {
                                    background: #ec7211;
                                    border: 1px solid #ec7211;
                                    color: #FFFFFF;
                                    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                                }
                                
                                .btn-primary:hover {
                                    color: #FFFFFF;
                                    background: #eb5f07;
                                }
                                
                                .btn-primary:active {
                                    background: #dd6b10;
                                }
                                
                                .inputBox {
                                    padding: 6px 12px;
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    font-family: sans-serif;
                                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                                    border-radius: 4px;
                                    font-family: Amazon Ember,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                                    resize: none;
                                    width: 420px;
                                }
                                
                                textarea.inputBox {
                                    height: 80px;
                                }
                                
                                input.inputBox {
                                    height: 80px;
                                }
                                
                                a {
                                    text-decoration: none;
                                }
                                
                                a:focus, a:hover {
                                    text-decoration: underline;
                                }
                                
                                a, a:focus, a:hover {
                                    color: #0073bb;
                                }
         
                                #papercutExit {
                                    position: absolute;
                                    top: 0;
                                    right: 0;
                                    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                                    height: 30px;
                                    width: 30px;
                                    font-size: 30px;
                                    line-height: 30px;
                                    text-align: center;
                                }
                                
                                #papercutExit:hover,
                                #papercutExit:focus {
                                    color: #000000;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                }
                                
                                #papercutInfo {
                                    position: absolute;
                                    bottom: 0;
                                    right: 10px;
                                    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                                    font-size: 12px;
                                    line-height: 30px;
                                    text-align: right;
                                }
                                
                                #papercutInfo:hover,
                                #papercutInfo:focus {
                                    color: #000000;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                }
                                
                            </style>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                            <div style="padding: 20px;">
                                <span id="papercutExit" class="papercutModalLink" onclick="window.parent.closePapercut();">&times;</span>
                            
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 0; padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2; font-size: 16px;">Submit an IDQ Request</h2>
                                    <form id="papercutForm" method="get" action="https://internal_ticketsystem.com/create/options?" target="_blank">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="Colour Change"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_type" value="Regular+Ticket"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="severity" value="TWENTY"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="Catalogue"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="subcat" value="Support"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="Changes"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Hello,
                                    I have the following issue:
                                    "/>  

                                        <span id="papercutBox">
                                            <p>Which Issue do you see?</p>
                                            <p><textarea name="description" required="required" class="inputBox"></textarea></p>
                                            
                                            <p>Which country is affected?</p>
                                            <p>
                                            <select name="title" class="inputBox selectDropdown">
                                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="" hidden="hidden"></option>
                                                <option value="24">DM</option>
                                                <option value="15">TR</option>
                                                <option value="36">US</option>
                                                <option value="79">FR</option>
                                                </select>
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                            <p>Which company is affected?</p>
                                            <p>
                                            <select name="title" class="inputBox selectDropdown">
                                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="" hidden="hidden"></option>
                                                <option value="123">company A</option>
                                                <option value="456">company B</option>
                                                <option value="789">company C</option>
                                                
                                            </select>
                                                                                
                                            <input type="hidden" name="description" value="

                                            ***CHOOSE THE DEFECT:***
                                            "/>                             
                                                                    
                                                                                    
                                            <p>Which area is impacted?</p>
                                            <p>
                                                <select name="description" class="inputBox selectDropdown">
                                                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="" hidden="hidden"></option>
                                                    <option value="blue">Image is blue but shouldnt</option>
                                                    <option value="red">Image is red but shouldnt</option>
                                                    <option value="green">Image is green but shouldnt</option>
                                    

                                            <input type="hidden" name="description" value="

                                            on following URL 
                                            "/>  

                                            <input id="ProductInput" type="hidden" name="description" value=""/>

                                                                
                                            </p>
                                            <p></p>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </span>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="window.parent.closePapercut();" class="btn">Close</button>
                                    </form>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $("#papercutForm").submit(function(event){
                                        console.log("Preventing default form submission")
                                        event.preventDefault();

                                        $("#ProductInput")[0].setAttribute("value", window.location.href.substr(0,250));

                                        /////// Handle inputs which have duplicate "name" attributes ///////

                                        // Handle multiple "title" query params
                                        var titleInputs = $("#papercutForm [name=title]")
                                        var titleInputsValues = $.map(titleInputs, function(elem) {
                                            return elem.classList.contains("selectDropdown") ? 
                                                ( elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text + "(" + elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value + ")" ) 
                                                : elem.value;
                                        });
                                        var formTitleValuesCombined = titleInputsValues.join(",");

                                        console.log(formTitleValuesCombined);


                                        // Handle multiple "description" query params
                                        var descriptionInputs = $("#papercutForm [name=description]")
                                        var descriptionInputsValues = $.map(descriptionInputs, function(elem) {
                                            return elem.classList.contains("selectDropdown") ? elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text : elem.value;
                                        });
                                        // Join the different descriptions with no space "" since the form-provided descriptions (non-user provided descriptions)
                                        // have newline character "\\n" at the beginning and end.
                                        // You could also delimit by newline character "\\n" just to be sure the descriptions show up on different lines.
                                        var formDescriptionValuesCombined = descriptionInputsValues.join("").replace(/\t/g, ""); // Replace tab characters

                                        console.log(formDescriptionValuesCombined);

                                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                                        // Inputs which have unique "name" attribute

                                        var allOtherInputs = $("#papercutForm [name]").not("[name=description]").not("[name=title]");


                                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // Build the target URL such that "title" and "description" both only appear once, 
                                        // so that each is interpretted as a single entiy rather than an array of inputs

                                        var url = new URL("https://internal_ticketsystem.com/create/options?");
                                        url.searchParams.append("title", formTitleValuesCombined);
                                        url.searchParams.append("description", formDescriptionValuesCombined);
                                        allOtherInputs.toArray().forEach( (elem) => {
                                            url.searchParams.append(elem.name, elem.value);
                                        });

                                        console.log("Redirecting to :", url.href);
                                        window.open(url.href, "_blank"); // Open the ticket form in new window
                                    });         

                                document.querySelector("#papercutForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        window.parent.submittedPapercut();
                                    }, 1);
                                });
                            </script>
                            </body>
                            </html>
                        '></iframe>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            `).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn(300);
     
        
            window.closePapercut = function() {
                $('#papercutModal').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
            }
            
            
            window.submittedPapercut = function() {
                    $('#papercutFrame').contents().find('#papercutBox').html('<p>Thanks for sending &#128578;</p>');
                $('#papercutCard').height(300);
            }
            
            
            $('#papercutModal').click(function() {
                window.closePapercut();
            });
      }
    );})()
```

I already found some useful results on stackoverflow, but I really struggle with the implementation :(

E.g. I found [On my webpage, using "window.location.href" returns "about:srcdoc" instead of the URL name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588349/on-my-webpage-using-window-location-href-returns-aboutsrcdoc-instead-of-th) - but if I enter i.e.

```
  let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
  $("#ProductInput")[0].setAttribute("value",iframe.contentDocument.baseURI);
```

instead of

```
  $("#ProductInput")[0].setAttribute("value", window.location.href.substr(0,250));
```

my code breaks :(

Can anyone help me understanding how I need to tweak the script to get the URL instead of 'about:srcdoc'?

Thank you!

Comment: If you get `about:srcdoc` as the location, it means you're in an iframe whose content didn't directly come from a url. (You might be able to get a containing page's url with `window.top.location` or `window.parent.location` though there are some security features that can prevent this.)

Comment: omg, it works! thank you so much, that was waaaaaay easier than I thought it would be! I'd love to accept your answer as solution, but you'd need to post it as a standalone answer :)